# Does this video show an Israeli officer saying that Hamas is not who killed, raped, slaughtered and beheaded?

Tags: israel, israel-hamas-war, hamas

[This tweet-video](https://twitter.com/DrJamal11/status/1723550864223187269) has been published for more than a month. The behavior of social media and search engines is very suspicious because I couldn't find this video anywhere else, except in the Arabic-twitter.

Its text (the Arabic translation of what the Israeli officer say in Hebrew, likely) reads:

> يقول الضابط الاسرائيلي: من قتل واغتصب وذبح،
> ومن قطع الروؤس هم المواطنون (الإسرائيليون) لم يكونوا حماس كانوا المواطنين.
> هذا الذي لا يفهمونه ان هؤلاء كانوا المواطنين. حماس جاؤوا وفتحوا وقتلوا الجنود وتقدموا للأمام.
> من جاء واغتصب وقتل وعمل كل هذه الفضائع هم المواطنون الاسرائيليون. هذا ما يحتاجه العالم ليفهموا.
> المذيع: هل رأيت ذلك؟
> الضابط: رأيت ذلك بأُم عين

> **Google Translate:** The Israeli officer says: Whoever kills, rapes, and slaughters, Those who beheaded were the (Israeli) citizens. They were not Hamas, they were the citizens.
> What they don't understand is that these were citizens. Hamas came, conquered, killed the soldiers and moved forward.
> The ones who came, raped, killed, and did all these atrocities were Israeli citizens. This is what the world needs to understand.
>
> Broadcaster: Did you see that?
>
> Officer: I saw that with my own eyes

Is this what the Israeli officer says in Hebrew?

Is the Israeli officer saying that Hamas is not who killed, raped, slaughtered and beheaded and that it was Israelis?

Comment: Does anyone know the name of the channel shown in the video?

Comment: Just from a google image search of the logo it seems to be [Hodhod network](https://hodhodpal.com/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

Just from the video that appear in the tweet it's clear that he blames Gazan citizens in addition to Hamas activists, and not Israeli citizens.

It's immediately clear from the Hebrew text in the video that it blames Gazan citizen as the words

> אזרחי עזה ביצעו את רוב הזוועות

prominently appear on the video, which means

> Gazan citizens committed most of the atrocities.

[image]

And listening to the words, he doesn't say Israeli at any point. From context he clearly blames **Gazan** citizen in the atrocities and not just Hamas activists.

Not only that the word Israel doesn't appear, also the second translation is wrong:

This is the correct translation

> Hamas came, **opened**, killed soldiers and moved forward. The ones who came, raped, killed, and did all these atrocities were citizens. This is what the world needs to understand.

From the context of the word "opened" it's clear that Hamas opened the holes in the walls that allowed **Gazan** citizen to enter Israeli territory and commit the atrocities.

Some of the replies to the tweet are able to identify it and say that the translation is deceptive.

[image]

This video is from an interview by Avi Nahmani from the online outlet [Rebel News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebel_News), which can be fully seen (with English sibtitles) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfExbSJfumw&list=PL2HWRRSziC_ECcL81ZXf8MpQQvH3ojXuH&index=15&ab_channel=RebelNews).

The speaker is a Special Forces reservist who lives in [Moshav Yesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesha,_Israel) and was at home on Oct. 7<sup>th</sup> and took part in the fighting, first as an unarmed citizen and later as the only armed person in his Moshav until IDF forces came after about 4 hours.

The snippet in the tweet appears at 7:20. Starting at 7:00 it gives even more context, as he starts by speaking about Gazan citizens.

> I tell you, as a civilian that lives here, all these years I said I though like this in my naivety, well, there's Hamas. That's what Hamas does, there are also poor civilians. You say there are poor civilians in Gaza. And I am right-wing, I'm not some kind of leftist. I tell you, there are civilians you say who are poor. Who slaughtered, who raped, who murdered, who beheaded?

Just before the snippet appearing in the tweet.

Also, a side point, the speaker is not an officer, he is a [Master Sargent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Defense_Forces_ranks).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150423/discussion-on-answer-by-simel-does-this-video-show-an-israeli-officer-saying-tha); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.